# Как отцентрировать заголовок относительно контентной части?

Tags: html, css

Ширина контентной части моего сайта – 1600рх. Вопрос: как расположить заголовок по центру именно контентной части, а не окна браузера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задать контентной части `text-align: center` или же так:

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
</div>
```

Только заголовок уже не будет заполнять блок.